# Проверка регистрации по чеку определенной надписи на странице

Tags: c#

Как  реализовать проверку на успешность, например регистрации аккаунта, по чеку определенной надписи на web странице, например "**Аккаунт зарегистрирован**",(использую фреймворк "`ViKing.ApplicationFramework`" если код покажется вам немного другим)) вот код проверки по хидерам:

```
// Выполняем запрос
post = String.Format("request.key={0}&action=step3&profile.password1={1}&profile.password2={1}&captcha.code={2}&profile.question=qweqwe&profile.customquestion=qweqwe&profile.answer=qweqwe&profile.gender=m&profile.birthday.day=13", key, pass, captcha);
var ans = Request("http://site.com/", post);

// Проверка корректности регистрации
if (ans.Headers["Location"] != "/checkcookie")
    throw new Exception("Not registered");

// Записываем акк в файл
akks.AppendLine(String.Format("{0}:{1}", login, pass));
Log("Registered akk: {0}:{1}", login, pass);
```

Comment: Я, честно говоря, ничего не понял :)

Вам не кажется, что это плохая затея определять результат по тексту на странице? Или вы бота пишете какого?

Что вам мешает просто получить всю страницу в стринг и поискать по строке потом?

Comment: Пишу регер, точнее он готов и работоспособен, но я хочу чтобы проверка проходила по чеку записи в страницах а не через хедиры, просто частенько возникают такие ситуации что вариант с хидерами не прокатывают.

"Что вам мешает просто получить всю страницу в стринг и поискать по строке потом?"
Интересно а можно пример???Просто я новичек по C#, язык сильно понравился вот и потихоньку познаю азы любыми способами, и все ответы бывалых сохроняю как пример у  себя на последок...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510212/how-i-can-get-web-pages-content-and-save-it-into-the-string-variable

Comment: Спасибо всем ответившим, сам разобрался вот код если кому понадобится:


            // Проверка корректности регистрации
            if (login.ContentUTF8.Contains("Зарегистрирован"))
            {
        // Записываем акк в файл
        akks.AppendLine(String.Format("{0}:{1}", login, pass));
        Log("Registered akk: {0}:{1}", login, pass);
           }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Bad");
         }